# checkbox scroll down in IE11 and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

- I have popup with list of checkboxes. When I select one of the check
  box it scrolls down.

  - Where as if I select all checkboxes it does not scroll down.
  - It happens in chrome and IE11 but it does not happen in firefox.
  - Not sure how to fix it since I am not sure is it happening due to js
    or css or html. can you guys tell us how to fix it
  - providing my code below.

Comment: Can you provide a link to live site or fiddle replicating this problem?

Comment: @hopkins-matt its a huge application its tough to reproduce in fiddle